# Cloning Jenkins workspace followed by moving directory within workspace

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Given a workspace folder structure of:

/foo/bar/index.html,
/foo/bar/index2.html

I need to clone that workspace so that any files within the "bar" folder are moved to the root of the workspace for the next downstream project. So the end result would be:

/index.html, /index2.html

I am using the Jenkins [clone plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clone+Workspace+SCM+Plugin) currently. I do not have sudo access so using the shell is not an option to move the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 'Execute Shell' as the first build step in your Jenkins project configuration and add:

```
mv foo/bar/* .
rm -rf foo/
```

This will move the contents of bar/ to the root directory of your workspace and then remove the foo/ directory only leaving behind index1.html and index2.html